# Error when setting location based reminders in Swift 2 Xcode 7 Beta 4

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, swift2

I want to set a location based reminder. This is my code:

```
    let locattionnotification = UILocalNotification()
    locattionnotification.alertBody = textAllert
    locattionnotification.regionTriggersOnce = false
    locattionnotification.region = CLCircularRegion(circularRegionWithCenter: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:
        mylatitude, longitude: mylongitude), radius: 300.0, identifier: "Location1")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(locattionnotification)
```

mylatitude and mylongitude are double values. The problem is, that Xcode is complaining:

> init(circularRegionWithCenter:radius:identifier:)' is unavailable: APIs >deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

Is there any better way to set the region based reminder? I already did some research, and saw that it is also possible with CLRegion, but couldn't figure out how to set it up with manually set coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [another `CLCircularRegion` constructor](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLCircularRegion_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLCircularRegion/initWithCenter:radius:identifier:):

```
locattionnotification.region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:
    mylatitude, longitude: mylongitude), radius: 300.0, identifier: "Location1")
```

Comment: This answer appears to break the region Notify on Exit and Notify on Entry properties for UILocalNotification. The following code         "locationnotification.region.notifyOnExit = false" no longer works because swift complains that "Value of optional type 'CLRegion?' not unwrapped." How can I get this part of it to work?

Comment: Change to `locationnotification.region!.notifyOnExit = false`. And learn about [optional types](http://lithium3141.com/blog/2014/06/19/learning-swift-optional-types/) - you will encounter them very often.